# CSS styling changing when I resize my screen

Tags: html, css

I created a feature box with some help on my WordPress development site. I want to  make this feature box responsive so it looks good on mobile devices.

It's almost working, but when I reduce my screen size the red ribbon on [my site](http://bryancollins.eu/wp/)'s feature box disappears, and my list style changes from a picture to another style.

How can I fix this?

```
.featured-box {
  border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: visible;
    width: auto;    
    max-width: 1160px; 
}

.featured-box h4 {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;

}

.myimage {

    float:right;
}

.featured-box p {
    padding: 0 0 20px;
}

.featured-box ul {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}

.featured-box ul li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
    padding: 0;
    align: right;
}

.featured-box .enews p {
    padding: 10 10 10 10px;
    color: #fff;
    float: left;
    width: 220 px;
    margin: 10 10 10 10px;

}

.featured-box .enews #subscribe {
    padding: 20 20 20 20px;;

}

.featured-box .enews #subbox {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    width: 300px;

}

.featured-box .enews .myimage {

      float: right;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 50px;
       width: auto;
}

section.enews-widget {
   overflow: hidden;
}


.featured-box .enews input[type="submit"] { 
background-color: #d60000;
     padding: 10 10 10 10px;
     width: 150px;

}



@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1139px) {
    div.featured-box {
        margin-top: 135px;

    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1140px) {
    div.featured-box {
        margin-top: 70px;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 section.enews-widget {
   clear: both;
 }
 .myimage {
   float: none;
 }
 .myimage img {
   display: block;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0 auto;
 }


}

#text-4 > div:nth-child(1) > h4:nth-child(1) {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 1.3em; font-weight: normal;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            background-color: #d60000; 
            position: relative;
            margin: 0px -60px 20px -20px;
            padding: 18px 0px 16px 20px;

}

#text-4 > div:nth-child(1) > h4:nth-child(1):after {
                content: '';
                display: block; height: 40px; width: 40px;
                background: url(http://bryancollins.eu/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/fold.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
                position: absolute; right: 0px; bottom: -40px;

}

.page p { line-height: 1.2em; }
.page a { color: #1badd2; text-decoration: none; }
.widget li  { 

                margin: 0;  
                padding: 2px 0px 8px 35px; 
                display: inline; position: relative; 
                border-bottom: none;

            }


.featured-box .widget li {
                list-style: none;
                background: url("http://bryancollins.eu/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/arrow.png") no-repeat scroll 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
                display: inline;
                margin: 0 0 0 30px;
                padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}
```

HTML below:

```
        <div class="widget-wrap"></div>
    </section>
    <section id="enews-ext-3" class="widget enews-widget">
        <div class="widget-wrap">
            <div class="enews">
                <h4 class="widget-title widgettitle">

                    33 Creative Strategies for your next writing proje…

                </h4>
                <p>

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing…

                </p>
                <div class="arrows">
                    <ul>
                        <li>

                            List item 1

                        </li>
                        <li>

                            List item 2

                        </li>
                        <li>

                            List item 3

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <p>

                    Tuo vero id quidem, inquam, arbitratu. Illud mihi …

                </p>
                <form id="subscribe" name="33 Creative Strategies for your next writing project" onsubmit="if ( subbox1.value == 'First Name') { subbox1.value = ''; } if ( subbox2.value == 'Last Name') { subbox2.value = ''; }" target="_blank" method="post" action="<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form --> <div id="mc_embed_signu…s="button"></div> </form> </div> <!--End mc_embed_signup-->">
                    <label class="screenread" for="subbox">

                        E-Mail Address

                    </label>
                    <input id="subbox" type="email" required="required" name="" onblur="if ( this.value == '' ) { this.value = 'E-Mail Address'; }" onfocus="if ( this.value == 'E-Mail Address') { this.value = ''; }" value="E-Mail Address"></input>
                    <input id="subbutton" type="submit" value="Subscribe"></input>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Remove the media queries used for it

Comment: You forgot the html markups! Attach them so we can see the construction.

Comment: If 'red ribbon' is an image, you must define width in %?

Comment: I updated my question with HTML, I created the red ribbon using CSS and also by using an image. The CSS provides the rectangular part of the ribbon. I added triangle as a GIF file to the bottom right of this ribbon. You can see this in #text-4 >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing actually logically wrong with how you used your media queries - the problem is actually a tiny typo. A few lines above the relevant styles for formatting the `<h4>` and `<li>` elements in "style.css", you'll find these lines of code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1140px) {
    div.featured-box {
        margin-top: 70px;
    }
```

Note how there's no closing brace (I didn't accidentally leave it out). This little omission is causing all styles below the media query to be included in it, so they'll only appear when the screen width is 1140px or greater. Adding the closing brace seems to cause it to behave as expected.

Running your CSS through a validator can help point you towards the problem. I tried using this [W3 CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/), and it indicated a Parse Error on the media query just below the unclosed one (which makes sense, since you can't nest media queries).

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

A thing About Css is difference between use of "px" and "%"

Mobile webpages. %'s rock for that. As it will (obviously) adjust to suit.

However when you want a fixed width for say example an article of text that you want displayed in a certain way, px's is the winner.

So for your Page to work good in Mobile ..try Replacing px to %

For best Avoid px , use %

Comment: Which values should I change from PX to %?